# FusedLocationProviderClient - App stops receiving location updates on Foreground Service

Tags: android, foreground-service, fusedlocationproviderclient

My app stops receiving location updates in a foreground service that has a loop to send telemetry data to a server. I use GCM (Firebase) to communicate with the app and I can kill the service and restart it remotely. If the service is receiving the location updates and I kill it when I restart it continues to send the location information.

**But, for no apparent reason, it stops receiving location updates (the little arrow icon on the notification bar disappears and the telemetry data sent to the server shows no location [lat, long] info) and even if I kill and restart the service, the location is not passed forward.**

It also occurs when I boot the cellphone with the service running. I can detect the boot and restart the service, but the location manager is not awakened, remains stationary.

If I click on the icon, it starts to receive location updates again.

I'm using the **Fused Location Provider Client API**.

```
public void requestLocationUpdates() {
    if (!isRequestingUpdates){
        Log.e(TAG, "requestLocationUpdates: Requesting location updates");
        isRequestingUpdates = true;

        try {
            mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest,
                    mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
            Log.e(TAG, "requestLocationUpdates: inside Try");
        } catch (SecurityException unlikely) {
            isRequestingUpdates = false;
            Log.e(TAG, "Lost location permission. Could not request updates. " + unlikely);
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone give me some pointers?